# Many-to-many relationship not working in a join query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I've spent 3 days investigating and trying to figure out how to resolve the following issue, but I failed.

My problem is that hibernate generates the following query:

```
Hibernate: select distinct bankgroupe0_.id as col_0_0_, bankgroupe0_.name as col
_1_0_, bankentity1_.name as col_2_0_ from bank_groups bankgroupe0_ inner join banks bankentity1_ on
```

when I'm executing the query on method findAllBankGroupTuples() from the Repository below. It seems that it doesn't recognize the many-to-many mapping in join. It obviously fails as it ends on "on" keyword and neither provides a join condition nor uses the intersection table (BANK_GROUPS_MAPPINGS - DDL below).
However, I can also find the following query in the log (produced because of the EAGER FetchType which I put there just to test if that works for other queries, performed without join):

```
Hibernate: select banks0_.group_id as group_id1_1_0_, banks0_.bank_id as bank_id2_1_0_, bankentity1_.id as id1_2_1_, bankentity1_.name as name4_2_1_ from bank_groups_mappings banks0_ inner join banks bankentity1_ on banks0_.bank_id=bankentity1_.id where banks0_.group_id=?
```

So I can see that Hibernate is able to recognize that many-to-many relationship when there is no join in the query. The query above is executed successfully.

Repository:

```
public interface BankGroupRepository extends CrudRepository<BankGroupEntity, Long> {

@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT new com.api.entity.BankGroupTuple(bg.id, bg.name, b.name) FROM BankGroupEntity bg join BankEntity b")
List<BankGroupTuple> findAllBankGroupTuples();
```

}

BankGroupEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BANK_GROUPS")
public class BankGroupEntity implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name="ID")
private int id;

@Column(name="NAME")
private String name;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "BANK_GROUPS_MAPPINGS",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="GROUP_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "BANK_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")})
private List<BankEntity> banks;

BankGroupEntity() {

}

BankGroupEntity(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public List<BankEntity> getBanks() {
    return banks;
}

public void setBanks(List<BankEntity> banks) {
    this.banks = banks;
}
}
```

BankEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BANKS")
public class BankEntity implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private int id;

@Column(name="NAME")
private String name;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "banks")
private List<BankGroupEntity> bankGroups;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public List<BankGroupEntity> getBankGroups() {
    return bankGroups;
}

public void setBankGroups(List<BankGroupEntity> bankGroups) {
    this.bankGroups = bankGroups;
}
}
```

Database:

```
create table BANK_GROUPS
(
ID INTEGER not null
    constraint BANK_GROUPS_ID_PK
        primary key,
NAME VARCHAR(40) not null
);

create table BANKS
(
ID INTEGER
    constraint BANKS_ID_PK
        primary key,
NAME VARCHAR(40) not null
);

create table BANK_GROUPS_MAPPINGS
(
GROUP_ID INTEGER not null
    references BANK_GROUPS,
BANK_ID INTEGER not null
    references BANKS,
constraint BANK_GROUPS_MAPPINGS_PK
    primary key (GROUP_ID, BANK_ID)
);

alter table BANK_GROUPS_MAPPINGS
add foreign key (GROUP_ID) references BANK_GROUPS;

alter table BANK_GROUPS_MAPPINGS
add foreign key (BANK_ID) references BANKS;
```

JPA settings:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

Database I'm using is DB2.

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance

After suggestion that I can't use constructor with join, I've changed method to following:

```
public interface BankGroupCrudRepository extends CrudRepository<BankGroupEntity, Long> {

@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT bg.id, bg.name, b.name FROM BankGroupEntity bg join BankEntity b")
List<Object[]> findAllBankGroupTuples();
}
```

And the outcome is exactly the same - it produces query ending with "on"

Comment: You can't use a new constructor with a join.

Comment: @K.Nicholas I removed the constructor and the result is exactly the same. Please see my post edited - I've added description at the end of it

Comment: use `join bg.banks b`

Comment: Thanks. Removing the constructor and changing join query made it work!